# How do you call a private class function (with parameters), in a public function of the same class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax

So, I'm writing up a program that is focusing on operator overloading.

I'm trying to write up a private function to find the least common denominator of two rational numbers (objects in main). Right now, the accessor just doesn't like the parameters of the private lcd function.

here's my lcd private function:

```
long CRational::lcd(const CRational &rationalNumber) const{
    long gCF = 0;
    long lCD = 0;
    if (m_denominator != 0 && rationalNumber.m_denominator != 0){
        gCF = gcf(m_denominator, rationalNumber.m_denominator);
        lCD = ((m_denominator / gCF)*rationalNumber.m_denominator);
    }

    return lCD;
}
```

Here's what I attempted for the accessor:

```
long CRational::getLCD() const
{

    return lcd(const CRational &rationalNumber);
}
```

Right now, I'm getting red squigglies under the const and &rationalNumber.
const - name type not allowed
&rationalNumber - unidentified

Was hoping someone could help me out before I go insane?

Comment: You need to give `lcd` an instance of `CRational`, but that's a declaration of `CRational const &`.

Comment: How do you call ***any*** function? This is not specific to private functions, public functions, or member functions. I see you have a `gcf` function that you're calling perfectly fine.

Comment: In `CRational::getLCD()`, are you trying to return the LCD of `this` `CRational` object?  Like: `return lcd(*this);`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
long CRational::getLCD(const Rational &rationalNumber) const
{
    return lcd(rationalNumber);
}
```

Comment: but then when I go to use the accessor in one of the member functions, won't it want me to enter a Rational object as a parameter?

Comment: @Keroro540 Well I don't understand why the function is `private` in the first place. If you just want to make it publicly available, make it public, don't add another public function calling it. And yes it will want that. Doing the lcd means having two numbers, so just put that second number in the accessor, like you would call `lcd` in the first place. But yea, accessors are for members, using one for a function  doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Keroro540 Yes... where else do you expect the second parameter to the LCD operation to come from?

Comment: @coyotte508 why else? Because it's a school project, and that's what the professor wants :\ All of the rationalNumber objects are given their values in main. Is there a way to use that objects data in the class?

Comment: @coyotte508
nvm. I'm an idiot. I was making this way too complicated in my head. Thanks a lot man, you helped me out a lot in getting my head back on the right line of thinking!